# YIi2 - comparing two field in searchModel

Tags: yii2

I have a table called TPurchasing which contain data about a store's purchasing record.

TPurchasing

- id | serial
- transaction_time | timestamp without time zone
- supplier | character varying(200)
- total | double precision
- paid | double precision

By using gii feature in yii2, I manage to generate a model called TPurchasingSearch from "CRUD Generator" menu. In the TPurchasingSearch, there is a function called search() which is used by the GridView in the view file.

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = TPurchasing::find();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'pagination' => ['pageSize' => 20],
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => ['defaultOrder' => ['transaction_time' => SORT_DESC]]
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere(['is_removed' => 0]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'supplier_name', $this->supplier_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'payment_type', $this->payment_type])
        ->andFilterWhere(['>', 'total', 'paid']);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Right now I'm trying to display records that is still not totally paid off, which means the "paid" column is smaller than "total" column. How can I do this comparison in the search function? The above code gave me an error:

```
invalid input syntax for type double precision: "paid"
```

on this part

```
->andFilterWhere(['>', 'total', 'paid']);
```

since it tried to compare total column with string "paid". I might missed it, but I can't seem to find the related answer in Yii2 documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `andFilterWhere()` here, you could simply try :

```
 $query->andWhere('total > paid');
```

Comment: It does the trick! Never thought it will be that simple. Thanks!