# Yii2 MongoDb find comapre fields

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

it might be a silly question  yet I'm stuck, i want to find records where uuid and main_uuid not equal
im able to find records in mongo using below query in console
Mongo Collection

```
       {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ff2c31e731333aa7e3affca"),
            "main_uuid" : "c0f5ac89-8dc7-4b54-9cce-bafd523a30e5",
            "uuid" : "c0f5ac89-8dc7-4b54-9cce-bafd523a30e5"
         }
    =================================================
    mongoQuery working in console=>
db.ntc.cdr.find ( { $where : "this.uuid != this.main_uuid" } )
```

i have tried [YIi2 - comparing two field in searchModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049361/yii2-comparing-two-field-in-searchmodel/46050492#46050492) as well but didn't worked!!

```
   class Cdr extends ActiveRecord
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public static function collectionName()
        {
            return [MONGO_DB, 'ntc.cdr'];
        }
        
    
    }
    
    class CdrSearch extends Cdr{
        $query = Cdr::find();

         $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query
        ]);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: The post you linked has to do with the interpretation on database level, not with the active record implementation. What adapter/package are you using to access mongodb from Yii2?

Comment: i'm using https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb i want exactly result as shown in that link ,my mistake.

Comment: Did you set `all()` at the end? What does this query - `Cdr::find()->where("this.uuid != this.main_uuid")->all()` return?

Answer (score 0):

For ActiveRecord if you want compare as equal should be

```
 Cdr::find()->where(['=', 'main_uuid' , 'uuid'])->all();
```

or simply

```
Cdr::find()->where('main_uuid = uuid')->all();
```

if you want NOT equal  then  use `!=` instead  of `=`

Comment: I'm guessing the `=` should be `!=` here.

Comment: @ArSeN  thanks  .. answer updated  for both operator

Comment: updated question kindly look none of above worked , i already tried.

Comment: You have an error ? ..show me the error message

Comment: I'm not getting any error, but also not getting an appropriate result , filter is not applying i mean, pic attached in question if  you can have some hint.

Comment: need equal , although any of the condition does not seem to be applying